# Jssor non-jquery slider. multiple slider on one page

Tags: javascript, slider

Is there way to put multiple sliders on a single page?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given 2 sliders in one page, the first is 'slider1', the second is 'slider2'

```
<script>
    jssor_slider1_starter = function (containerId) {
        ...
    };
    jssor_slider2_starter = function (containerId) {
        ...
    };
</script>
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px;
    height: 300px;">
    ...
    <script>
        jssor_slider1_starter('slider1_container');
    </script>
</div>
<div id="slider2_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px;
    height: 300px;">
    ...
    <script>
        jssor_slider2_starter('slider2_container');
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: And, If we Have a Dynamic amount of sliders? basically I don´t know the name of Slider Container

Comment: Please ask a new question and include your code in the question.

Comment: Nevermind, I thought about calling $JssorSlider$ and passing a Class of all divs I want to make it slider!