# How to add more than one Jssor Slider in One HTML page (Updated jssor Source)

Tags: jssor

I have just started using JSSOR (for sliding elements) http://www.jssor.com/ and I'm wondering if there can be more than one element sliding on the same page.

Please illustrate whole process on where to add codes and all Help will be Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every slider should have an unique id.

Given a slider with id `jssor_1` is on a page.

To add another slider to the page, you can make the second slider with another id (i.e. `jssor_2`)

Reference:
[How to put up many jssor sliders on one page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497060/how-to-put-up-many-jssor-sliders-on-one-page)