# Multi slide JSSOR SLIDE

Tags: slider, jssor

I see that in code jssor slider:

```
var jssor_slider2 = new $JssorSlider$('slider2_container', options);
```

Here "slider2_container" is a id. I want use "class" replace for "id" . 
How to i can do it ?. Because i used multi slide in a page. So that if it is "id" , it only run slide  first , remainder not working. Help me !

Answer (score 1):

You can use different id for different slider.

```
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);
var jssor_slider2 = new $JssorSlider$('slider2_container', options);
```

Reference: [Jssor non-jquery slider. multiple slider on one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466300/jssor-non-jquery-slider-multiple-slider-on-one-page)